# Make fmt.sprintf not to replace %s in variables

Tags: go

If I wanted to do the following:

```
    a := "%shello%s"
    b:= fmt.Sprintf("%sWorld",a)
    fmt.Printf(b)
```

I want to print

```
 %shello%sWorld
```

ie  %s is replaced only in %sWorld.

How can i do that?

I do not want to replace a with `%%shello%%s`

Comment: Since the dawn of time (1/1/1970) C programmers have been using `printf(s)` rather than printf("%s", s) or just puts(s).  In Go you can use os.Stdout.WriteString(b).

Answer (score 7):

```
a := "%shello%s"
b:= fmt.Sprintf("%sWorld",a)
```

This works just fine, it results in a string being `"%shello%sWorld"`.

The problem is with how you print it:

```
fmt.Printf(b)
```

**[`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) treats `b` as a format string**, and since `b`'s value contains `%s`, this expects you to also pass arguments (which you haven't), so the actual output contains error messages.

Instead print it with [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println):

```
fmt.Println(b)
```

And output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bRbaVAIkEPd)):

```
%shello%sWorld
```

Comment: @jibin-mathews, notice the naming pattern of the functions in `fmt`: they are named like `[f|s]print[f|ln]` (modulo title character casing); the root verb is obviously "print", the prefix, if present, designates where the result is output: means "file" when it's "f" and "string" when it's "s"; if the prefix is absent, the output is the standard output stream of the running process. The suffix, if present, controls treatment ot the input: "f" stands for "formatted" and means the 1st argument—the string—is not taken verbatim but is scanned for specal placeholders…

Comment: … "ln" means "line" and makes sure a full line, terminated with the line feed character is output. The naming of the scanning family of functions basically follows the same pattern. All-in-all, contemplating `go doc fmt` is highly advised.